# Custom signal does not work

Tags: django, django-signals

I created a signal:

```
sig_published = Signal()
```

This signal is placed in a signals.py, which I import in my models.py:

```
from signals import sig_published
```

and in the model file's footer, I connect it to a function which for testing purposes just prints out a debug string.:

```
def update_mode(sender, **kwargs):
    print "UPDATING"
sig_published.connect(update_mode, sender=MyModel)
```

Now, in my save()-Method, I try to send a signal:

```
sig_published.send(sender=self)
```

but it does not print out anything. If I try a built-in signal like pre_save:

```
pre_save.connect(update_mode, sender=MyModel)
```

it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you maybe also show us your `save` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're emitting the signal with `sender` equal to your model's *instance*, while in connect you're matching against `MyModel` *class*. Those two aren't the same object, so your receiver ignores the signal. You can compare with [`pre_save` emitting code](https://github.com/lqc/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L473), that it uses a class, not an instance.

Comment: oh my, that's it, thank you. I changed the listener to sig_published = Signal(providing_args=['instance']) and the senders accordingly, and that works.